# ReactJs: Mulitiple Axios calls in componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, axios

I want to fetch data from my API (Spring Boot) to my front-end app on React, everything is working fine on the server-side.

Now I have a component named HomePage, where I want to fetch the array of Articles from my API. The problem is, somehow I am getting multiple responses from which the first and second ones are empty arrays, and the third one is the normal array with the needed data.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      articles: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.loadArticles();
  }

  loadArticles(){
    articleService.fetchArticles().then((response) => {
      this.setState({
        articles: response.data
      })
    });
  }
```

By inspecting with the React DevTool extension, I can see that the state has successfully changed and yet my component doesn't re-render. (If I don't check if articles are empty I get an error which says the .map() is undefined, which means that when the component was rendered it state.articles was filled with the initial response which is always empty)

```
 render() {
        let { articles } = this.state.articles;

        return (
            <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-9">
                {articles && articles.map(article => <Article key={article.id} article={article}/>)}
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-3">
                widgets
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let { articles } = this.state;
```

not `let {articles} = this.state.articles`